# ASP.NET MVC - Saving nested collection data

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I am brand new to ASP.Net MVC. So, keep that in mind.  :)

I have a view with nested collections, with fields that get updated by the end user.

I have the updated model data successfully coming back from an AJAX call to my controller.

So... now i have a model with nested collection objects - where each item in collection also carries a collection. (BTW) This is a very low volume app.

I am not currently using EF - strictly using old fashion SQL calls and sprocs.

Is there an easy way to determine which values of my collection have been updated without out drawing out the whole collection from database again and iterating the whole thing? ugh...

Comment: Can you post the code of your model class?

Comment: There is no any direct way as such. But you have some options to look for. 1. You can use third party library which will store entire object with flag for each field if it is been changed. i.e. Knockout JS or Angular JS and track those flag at server side to do further operations. 2. You can maintain 2 copies of your object in your model one which will be used for UI and another just for reference so you can check against that copy before saving to db. 3 . Add one more property to your model which you can assign (,) separated names of changed elements and refer that on server side after post

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would use [Knockout Js](http://knockoutjs.com) and [Observable Arrays](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/observableArrays.html) will help you to track all changes on the View. Knockout tracks and updates all things automatically, you just need create Update() method and mark changable variables as observables.